# Why does a 50 Hz, 200 mV sine wave appear sometimes on my portable oscilloscope without a probe connected to anything?

Tags: voltage, current-measurement, oscilloscope, interference

I have a portable oscilloscope, and when I connect just one probe to it, sometimes, moving the probe into the air without connecting it to anything, then I can see (in some of the places of my house) a very stable 50 Hz sine wave of around 200 mV appear on the screen.

Its intensity varies as I walk (from 0 to almost 200 mV), being stronger when I am near an LCD screen, a wall switch, or next to the refrigerator. Ir sometimes also works a little when I am not close to anything, apparently.

Sometimes it varies also if I move my body and the scope and the probe stays in the same position.

As I don't believe in spirits,  I suspect that it may be some kind of 'induction' from the installation of the alternate current (50 Hz, in Spain) in my house that transmits itself 'into the air' (as my probe is never touching anything).
Could it be?

If that is true, how does it work?

Comment: Which portable oscilloscope it is and what kind of probes it has? Like multimeter probes with banana plugs or like real oscilloscope probes with BNC connector? Likely just capacitive  coupling picked up by the scope.

Comment: oh, but what if you did believe in spirits? you could have such fun ideas about what is happening

Answer (score 14):

The probe may be characterized by a **capacitive coupling**.
This make the probe acting like an antenna receiving *50 Hz* as power lines radiations.

Comment: The antenna is also the guy holding the oscilloscope.

Comment: Sure! A simple check by touching/connecting to a grounded conductor

Comment: This is a great object lesson introducing what might be the greatest nightmare in the microelectronic world - capacitive coupling, better known as *crosstalk.*

Answer (score 5):

It gets a lot worse than that. We regularly see people read 50-100 volts from that effect, and we're in 120V country!

Get an long extension cord, preferably 3-wire.  Also get a spool of hookup wire. Run the wire alongside the extension cord, e.g. tape them to each other with tape so they are very close. Don't twist.  Set your scope in 400V range and put it on the extra wire. Surprise!  You will see dozens if not hundreds of volts there.

That is capacitive coupling.  It drives electricians (people who wire buildings) *crazy*, especially when guiding novices using high-impedance DVMs, which are very sensitive to it.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the [grid hum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_hum).

The source is your power grid. Your probe may be coupled capacitively or in rare cases, inductively (near big transformers or motors). It may as well happen because of a ground loop inside the scope or between the scope and the circuit you are measuring.

Since you can control the coupling by moving yourself, it is most likely a capacitive coupling.

The phenomenon is not limited to oscilloscopes, it is a real pain in audio engineering and wherever a low-noise signal is dealt with.

One usually doesn't get a pure sine wave, because some of the coupling mechanisms are non-linear (e.g. corona discharge) and both the inductive and the capacitive coupling promote higher frequencies.

Ground everything and hope for the best.

Comment: And grid hum is like a fingerprint in time.  https://youtu.be/e0elNU0iOMY